# How to Make Timer Run in Background Xcode IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an issue with my app. I have a countdown timer that runs in the app. Initially before i made adjustments to the app delegate method: `applicationDidEnterBackground`, the timer would still run if i left the app.(Not closed the app, just in the home screen.)

I placed a notification trigger in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. This may have caused the timer to stop running.

I need to send a notification to the user to return to the app before the timer ends. (Hence the notification in `applicationDidEnterBackground`)
I want to give the user a certain time to return to the app before the timer stops.

Right now.... the notification is sent, but the timer ends immediately.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    //adding title, subtitle, body and badge
    content.title = "Hey if you will not come back"
    content.subtitle = "your timer will be killed"
    content.body = ""
    content.badge = 1
    //getting the notification trigger
    //it will be called after 5 seconds

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)

    //getting the notification request
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "SimplifiedIOSNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)


    //adding the notification to notification center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
 @objc func countdown (){

    if valueToInt != 0 {
        valueToInt -= 1
        sliderLabel.text = String(valueToInt)
    } else {
        endTimer()
    }

    sliderLabel.text = timeFormatted(valueToInt)
}


func startTimer() {

    countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector (ViewController.countdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    countdown()

    stopOutlet.isHidden = false
    startOutlet.isHidden = true
    titlleLabel.isHidden = true
    sliderView.isHidden = true

 }
```

Comment: what's initial value of `valueToInt` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not run any code in background continuously unless you explicitly ask for it. To do any background task you have to activit Background Modes. **Targets->Capabilities->Background Modes**
For the specific solution that you're looking you can ask system for some extra time in background without turning **Background Modes** on. Apple will give you're max time of 2min 59 seconds this is what I have tested but documentation only says under 3 minutes.

```
// Declare a background task by default I set it to TaskInvalid
var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
```

Before going to background mode initiate and begin the background task

```
backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: { [weak self] in
        self?.endBackgroundTask()
    })

// endBackgroundTask is a helper function which you will call once you're done with your task
private func endBackgroundTask() {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}
```

You can even call the endBackgroundTask function before you invalidate the timer

```
 @objc func countdown (){

if valueToInt != 0 {
    valueToInt -= 1
    sliderLabel.text = String(valueToInt)
} else {
    // call endBackgroundTask if you didn't call system will terminate it
    self.endBackgroundTask()
    endTimer()
}

   sliderLabel.text = timeFormatted(valueToInt)
}
```